# Why do I see Object.apply in the console, when there is no case i can use that on an object?

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome-devtools, apply

Why is `Object.apply` there in the console suggestions when there is no use case for the same,

[image]

only time we use APPLY method is while calling a function.

Its not even mentioned in the [mdn's js Object reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).
It's is there in the function's prototype in mdn.

and if there's some case when i can use apply while using an object, please let me know.

Comment: Apply is a property of function and `Object` is a function. Hence apply is available. Try `Typeof(Object)`

Comment: If you notice, `typeof(Object)` is "function". So, it has all method in Function.prototype (like call, apply).

And I, too, don't see any cases we need to use `Object.apply`.

Comment: @Vothaison, Please add this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is a function, and functions do have an `apply` method.

```
console.log(Object.constructor === Function);
```

as for all functions invoking apply calls the function, in other words if `F` is a function then `F(x, y, z)` is the same as `F.apply(this, [x, y, z])` (the first argument will be the value of `this` when inside the function).

From the specs (section 19) `Object` in Javascript (i.e. whatever is initially bound to the name "Object" in the global object) is a constructor that can be called with optional argument `x` and:

- If `NewTarget` is neither `undefined` nor the active function, then
  return `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%ObjectPrototype%")`. This means that calling `new Object()` is just like writing `({})`.
- If value is `null`, `undefined` or not supplied, return `ObjectCreate(%ObjectPrototype%)`. This means that calling `Object(undefined)` or `Object(null)` (without `new`) is also like writing `({})` to create a new standard object.
- Otherwise return `ToObject(value)`. This means that `Object(x)` calls a conversion to object. For example `Object(42)` will give you a boxed number but `Object(x)===x` if `x` is already an object.

IMO calling `Object.apply` is not going very frequent in Javascript programs (you can probably be an happy productive Javascript programmer for all your life without having to touch this kind of stuff).

Comment: can you tell me a use case of Object.apply ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Object` constructor is typically used to convert primitives into objects:

```
1 instanceof Number // false
```

but

```
Object(1) instanceof Number // true
```

So a possible (although quite artificial) use case of `Object.apply` would be converting the first element of an array of primitives into an object.

```
var singletonArray = ['foo'];
var foo = Object.apply(null, singletonArray);
// foo is an Object
// (foo instanceof String) === true
```

This may not be very useful, but since `Object` is a function, having the `.apply` method is not an exception, but the rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice, typeof(Object) is "function" -> It is a function. 
So, it has all methods from Function.prototype (like `call`, `apply`, `bind`, ...).

I, too, don't see any cases we need to use Object.apply.